# Java: FileReader cannot locate file even in same directoy

Tags: java, compiler-errors, bufferedreader, filereader

I'm currently working on a problem in Java which asks for a text file to be read. For some reason, I cannot correctly locate the file within my directory.

Here is my current directory structure:

```
com.company
- Main.java
- article.txt
```

Here is my current Main.java file --

```
package com.company;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       File file= new File("article.txt");

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    }
}
```

The error reads:

```
Unhandled exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException
```

I've also tried using the absolute path as well, but that does not work either (/Users/my_name/IdeaProjects/My_Project/src/com/company/article.txt)

Can anyone provide some insight?

Comment: Edited! It's article.txt

Comment: If you start application form IDE then relative path should be `src/com/company/article.txt`.

Comment: `new FileReader(...)` throws an exception. You aren't handling it. This is a *compilation error*. It has nothing to do with what it says in your title.

Comment: You do not have the exceptions handled. You can throw exception using `throws IOException` before `main` methods curly brace and your correct relative path for Windows will be `src\\com\\company\\article.txt`.

Comment: please [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if it's possible. Let it **re-producible**.

Answer (score -1):

The line with "new BufferedReader(...)" throws an exception (The new FileReader). The line with BufferedReader should instead be changed to:

```
BufferedReader br = null;

try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: `new File(...)` doesn't throw exceptions, but something else does. Close but no cigar.

Comment: @EJP Ah! You are correct. It is the BufferedReader line that throws the exception. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: You're still wrong. It is `new FileReader(...)` that throws the exception. There isn't any point in leaving your original mistake in the answer.